# Undo option in LatexDraw

Tags: pstricks

The GUI LatexDraw for generating PStricks codes does not have "undo" option. What other better GUIs are available for  generating PStricks codes?

http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` for undo, `Ctrl+Y` for redo in LatexDraw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl+Z` for undo, `Ctrl+Y` for redo in LateXDraw.